# Can I use paired t-test in this case?

Tags: covariance

I am a thesis student. I conducted an experiment on three  different schools. I took a class from each school and assumed that they are one group. I took one group and considered it as a control group. I used paired t test. 
The reader in my defense considered that I can't assume that students from each school as one group. He preferred Covariance test.

Please send me your  reply asap  based on scientific evidence.

Regards,

Teacher and Student

Comment: could you pls elaborate more about the details of your data.

Answer (score 4):

A paired t-test is for testing a difference in means between two groups that are somehow connected. For example, do husbands and wives have equal IQs? Are people right and left eyes equally acute? and so on.

You have 3 groups, not 2. You have no matching mechanism that I can see.  So, while you haven't really given us enough information, I can't see how the answer to your question could be "yes".

Comment: Can I consider the three treatment groups ( 3 groups of students from three schools who have similar background) as one especially that I'm using quasi-experimentaL? Also, in my research questions, I didn't consider the student background or even the school as a variable?

Comment: @hudaKaeen I think you need to give us a lot more info before we can figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not paired t-tests. Your samples (the classes) are independent. Assuming your dependant variable is a continuous score, you could run an Anova analysis, which is a generalization of the t-test for more than 2 groups. You could also run 2 or 3 distinct independant samples t-tests, but you'll need to take into account the risk of family-wise error. Look for "bonferroni adjustment" for more details.